# Change background color using toggle switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
<script>
document.getElementsByName("checkbox").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

body {
 background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

body {
 background-color: red;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br>

<script>
document.getElementsByName("checkbox").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm a bit of noob here, but I have this toggle switch that I want to change the whole body background which is currently red to black when I click it. But for some reason, my script doesn't work. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should try: document.getElementsByName("checkbox")[0].onclick = function() {myFunction()};

Answer (score 4):

The problem your code has is the click event is not registered with the checkbox because you are using the wrong method to get the element. Trying using id instead `getElementById`. Below is a solution. Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 60px;
      height: 34px;
    }
    
    .switch input {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ccc;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }
    
    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 26px;
      width: 26px;
      left: 4px;
      bottom: 4px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }
    
    input:checked+.slider {
      background-color: #2196F3;
    }
    
    input:focus+.slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }
    
    input:checked+.slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
      transform: translateX(26px);
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #BB9797;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

  <label class="switch">
  <input id="toggleSwitch" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("toggleSwitch").onclick = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

    function myFunction() {
      let color = document.body.style.background;
      if (color === 'black') {
        document.body.style.background = "#BB9797";
      } else {
        document.body.style.background = "black";
      }

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make 2 change here:

Firstly you should add array index number when you typing like  `document.getElementsByName("checkbox")[0]` because `getElementsByName` return array:

```
document.getElementsByName("checkbox")[0].onclick = function() {myFunction()};
```

Secondly you should add name `attribute` add in `checkbox` because you selecting element by `getElementsByName` but it is absent in your element:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
   <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

body {
 background-color: #BB9797;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br>

<script>
var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("checkbox")[0];
checkbox.onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
 if(checkbox.checked) { document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";}
 else {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#BB9797";}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is updated code just I add a new Id and function please check this solution I think it will work for you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

body {
 background-color: red;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input id="toggleSwitch" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br>
<script>
    document.getElementById("toggleSwitch").onclick = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

    function myFunction() {
      let color = document.body.style.background;
      if (color === 'black') {
        document.body.style.background = "red";
      } else {
        document.body.style.background = "black";
      }

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which, in my opinion, is a cleaner solution, is to use `classList.toggle` to toggle a class on the body element. This way you don't need to change any code if you need to redesign the colours. Only changes in CSS is required.

```js
document.getElementById("toggleSwitch").onclick = function() { myFunction() };

function myFunction() {
 document.body.classList.toggle("switch-on");
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.switch-on {
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  background-color: #BB9797;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input id="toggleSwitch" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('change');
  });
});
```

```css
body.change{
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
} 

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
 
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
} 

 input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

body {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

  <h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check the above code.